# Why is my functional component not re-rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component where I run this function on a button click:

```js
const dineroAsignado = parseFloat((dependencia.porcentaje_asignado * presupuesto.cantidadPresupuesto / 100).toFixed(2)) + 1000;
const centrosTrabajo = dependencias;
const index = centrosTrabajo.findIndex(ct => ct.id_centro_trabajo === dependencia.id_centro_trabajo);
centrosTrabajo[index].porcentaje_asignado = dineroAsignado * 100 / presupuesto.cantidadPresupuesto;
setDependencias(centrosTrabajo);
```

Everything is working fine, but the component doesn't re-renders on update.
I can't figure out why.

Can you please help me?
Thanks!

Comment: We update the state with `setState()`, and this is what typically triggers a re-`render`.  I do not see this being called?

Comment: It is a functional component. The setState is the last line, setDependencias(centrosTrabajo).

Comment: 'where I run this function on a button click:'  - this is no function. please show the complete function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are mutating the state reference instead of creating a new one and updating it.

```
const centrosTrabajo = dependencias; // <-- state reference

const index = centrosTrabajo.findIndex(
  (ct) => ct.id_centro_trabajo === dependencia.id_centro_trabajo
);
centrosTrabajo[index].porcentaje_asignado =
  (dineroAsignado * 100) / presupuesto.cantidadPresupuesto; // <-- mutation!!

setDependencias(centrosTrabajo); // saved reference back in state
```

## Solution

Create a new array reference for state. The easiest way is to shallow copy the array first. You also should shallow copy the element into a new object reference.

```
const centrosTrabajo = [...dependencias]; // <-- create new array reference

const index = centrosTrabajo.findIndex(
  (ct) => ct.id_centro_trabajo === dependencia.id_centro_trabajo
);

centrosTrabajo[index] = { // <-- create new object and copy existing
  ...centrosTrabajo[index],
  porcentaje_asignado: (dineroAsignado * 100) / presupuesto.cantidadPresupuesto,
};

setDependencias(centrosTrabajo); // <-- update state with new reference
```